# How to get Jest coverage for code in hooks, for functional component?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks

In functional component, there is this hook/function:

```
const [currentTab, setCurrentTab] = useState(index);
const handleTabChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, tab: number) => {
    console.log("test handleTabChange: " + tab);
    setCurrentTab(tab);
  };
```

The hook is being called by the test (console log), but the code in it missing coverage: "statement not covered".
I have a test that verify the side effect of this tab change - and it works fine.
How do I get coverage for this "black box" code?

Many thanks